# How to implement print effect like this page?

Tags: printing

http://losangeles.kijiji.com/c-PrintAd?AdId=167716102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of a page, and the print dialog will pop up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.print();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Viewing the page's source code, I see:

```
<body onload="OnLoad();window.print();" onunload="OnUnload()">
```

It's the `window.print();` you're interested in.

Although a matter of personal choice, I'm not a fan of web pages invoking system dialogs. It's that whole "don't take control of my computer" thing, like sites that maximize the browser, try to pop-up windows, etc. I'll call a link "Printer Friendly Version" rather than "Print this Page", assuming the user can figure out how to do File -> Print.

Comment: +1 I don't really like that kind of intrusive javascript, remind me too much the time when javascript was a language to make pron ad based popup ...